# Angular Routes not working with cloudfront + s3

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Currently only the default route on app start loads for my app in cloudfront. It works when I go to root of site using `cloudfront.[address].net`  I'm also using WAF to limit it to only my IP address, but when I go to cloudfront.[address].net/signup or /login then I get

[image]

How can I get the child routes to work too? I have my bucket policy

Bucket Policy

```
{
 "Version": "2008-10-17",
 "Statement": [
     {
         "Sid": "3",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
             "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E2SRF18SRG0FC7"
         },
         "Action": "s3:GetObject",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket]/*"
     }
 ]
}
```

I'm blocking all public access, but I'm also using cloudfront with an OAI so I don't think I need to worry about it being blocked since it's going through cloudfront.

[image]

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the cloudfront distribution's error document to your entry document(index.html)

Please ensure you have the following steps covered.

1. S3 bucket policy to allow only Cloudfront to do a GetObject
2. Cloudfront distribution's custom error response is set to `/index.html` for HTTP `404` and `403` error codes
3. Cloudfront distribution is in `deployed` state, because cloudfront may take longer and we could easily make an observational error

Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw another stackoverflow post that mentioned that so that's already been added. Here's a screenshot of my configuration there https://postimg.cc/sG5nSZfp

Comment: It may not do anything but can you configure the error document to index.html as well

Comment: First of all , has your cloudfront finished deploying

Comment: It's already set to index.html. See https://postimg.cc/sG5nSZfp for reference. Also cloudfront is fully deployed

Comment: It's the screenshot from S3. Can you set the error document on cloudfront.

Comment: I think you haven't set the custom error response for HTTP 403

Comment: You're correct. I haven't done anything with custom error responses. I don't really see the correlation, but I'm happy to configure it if that's what needs to happen. Can you advise how I would further configure this https://postimg.cc/4HbSqF7K to make ```/subRoutes``` work?

Comment: For the `403` error code, return `404` response code and set the error document as `/index.html`. Only for the error document don't miss the `/` in the front.

Comment: I added the ```/``` in error document and that seemed to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: glad to be of help.

Comment: i was also getting this error. If I set the custom error responses, it posts back /reloads when user clicks a button instead of routing. Can you please help?